# Point cluster in ArcGIS Javascript API 4.3?

Tags: javascript, point, clustering, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, spatial-cluster

I am trying to create a map with the the ArcGIS API for JavaScript v4.3. Some of the points that I want to visualize are on the same location and I would like to use some type of point clustering to render the points.

I checked the ESRI documentation for this version but I could not find something about clustering. 
 Is there a way to do point clustering in ArcGIS JS v4.3?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not possible through the [current version](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/capabilities/index.html) it is planned though as future updates occur for this version.

[ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.20](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html) Does have this capability.

Comment: I just found something that could be a solution. I will check it and get back. [link] (http://flareclusterlayer.azurewebsites.net/index_v4.html)

Comment: Which version will it come. 4.8 does not have it. Do you know? :)

Answer (score 2):

The GitHub page linked below contains a clustering example for v4.x (this if from the above comments)

https://github.com/nickcam/FlareClusterLayer